# Symfony app_dev.php leads to error 500

Tags: php, google-chrome, symfony, http-error

I am working on my first Symfony project and experiencing some strange problems. After developing mainly on my local machine I have now setup everything my hosted webspace (no root access to server).

Everything works fine when testing the webpage with Firefox, Safari or IE. But when I access the page with Chrome (latest version) most JavaScipts do not work. /app/log/prod.log shows several entries for related errors:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /js/500a0e0.js"
...
```

How is this possible while everything works fine with other browsers? Furthermore I cannot use `app_dev.php` with Chrome to investigate the problem any further. When using this front controller I just get an **error 500**. The same on all other browsers works fine.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: Put here the error 500 output and I recommend you that clear cache on symfony env prod and dev; and in chrome ctrl+f5.

Comment: Hi, I did not solve the problem with the JS files yet. But I figured out, that the ERROR 500 is caused by the x-chromelogger-data Header field, that Symfony sends back when Chorme is being used. It seems that this Header field is to large to be handeled by the server I am using.